# Get results from a terminated parfor

Tags: matlab, parfor

After a 1000 iterations parfor terminate due to an error, and all sliced outcome is gone.

The code have the form:

```
parfor i=1:2000    
B(i)=func(i)    
end
```

How do I get the result of 1000 iterations that already have been done?

Answer (score 1):

In `parfor`, you cannot get any results from a loop that terminates with an exception. However, you can use `try`/`catch` inside the loop

```
parfor i = 1:2000
  try
    B(i) = func(i);
  catch E
    B(i) = NaN;
  end
end
```

Or you could be just a little more sophisticated

```
parfor i = 1:2000
  try
    B(i) = func(i);
    OK(i) = true;
  catch E
    B(i) = NaN;
    OK(i) = false;
  end
end
```

This will allow you to determine precisely which iterations failed (useful in the case where `func(i)` might legitimately return `NaN`).